# WSO2 BAM 2.1.0 installation

Tags: wso2

I have installed WSO2 Bam 2.1.0 to my local environment and i have redirect my logs to bam. I could see my logs on cassandra however when i try to execute service_stats on bam i get exception. You could see the errors at the below.

Do you have any suggestion?

[2013-01-22 12:33:53,659] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.service.RSSAdmin} -  Error occurred while retrieving the database list of the tenant 'carbon.super'
org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.RSSManagerException: Error occurred while retrieving all databases
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.internal.dao.RSSDAOImpl.getAllDatabases(RSSDAOImpl.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.internal.manager.RSSManager.getDatabases(RSSManager.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.service.RSSAdmin.getDatabases(RSSAdmin.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.service.RSSAdmin.getDatabasesForTenant(RSSAdmin.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "D.ID" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT d.ID AS DATABASE_ID, d.NAME, d.TENANT_ID, s.NAME AS RSS_INSTANCE_NAME, s.SERVER_URL, s.TENANT_ID AS RSS_INSTANCE_TENANT_ID, d.TYPE  FROM RM_SERVER_INSTANCE s, RM_DATABASE d WHERE s.ID = d.RSS_INSTANCE_ID AND d.TENANT_ID = ? [42122-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:127)
    at org.h2.expression.Alias.optimize(Alias.java:47)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:738)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:202)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:214)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:434)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:384)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1071)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:63)
    at $Proxy20.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.internal.dao.RSSDAOImpl.getAllDatabases(RSSDAOImpl.java:277)
    ... 44 more
[2013-01-22 12:33:53,674] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager} -  Error initializing tenant Hive meta store.. 
org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.ui.stub.RSSAdminRSSManagerExceptionException: RSSAdminRSSManagerExceptionException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.ui.stub.RSSAdminStub.getDatabasesForTenant(RSSAdminStub.java:819)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.getHiveMetaDatabase(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.getRSSMetaStore(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.prepareRSSMetaStore(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getMetaStoreConnectionURL(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:85)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getJdoConnectionUrl(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[2013-01-22 12:33:53,678] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager} -  Error while retrieving setting the hive meta store for tenant domain:carbon.super
[2013-01-22 12:33:53,680] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext} -  Unable to fetch the JDO Connection URL for meta store..
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.getMetaDataStoreConnectionURL(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:275)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getMetaStoreConnectionURL(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getJdoConnectionUrl(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[2013-01-22 12:33:53,682] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error during query execution..
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fetch the JDO Connection URL for meta store..
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fetch the JDO Connection URL for meta store..
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.handleException(HiveContext.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.getMetaDataStoreConnectionURL(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:275)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getMetaStoreConnectionURL(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getJdoConnectionUrl(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:104)
    ... 11 more
[2013-01-22 12:33:53,684] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : service_stats_336
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error during query execution..
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fetch the JDO Connection URL for meta store..
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:91)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fetch the JDO Connection URL for meta store..
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.handleException(HiveContext.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.multitenancy.HiveRSSMetastoreManager.getMetaDataStoreConnectionURL(HiveRSSMetastoreManager.java:275)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getMetaStoreConnectionURL(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hive.data.source.access.util.DataSourceAccessUtil.getJdoConnectionUrl(DataSourceAccessUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:104)
    ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

Can you please put the complete exception trace? And Have you add tenants to BAM and are you running on tenant mode? What is the port offset you are using here?

You may need to update the $BAM_HOME/repository/conf/advanced/hive-rss-config.xml with correct details. as explained below:

rss-server-url - you can use the same BAM server/ external BAM server/ Storage server for this. Please put the correct server you are going to use for RSS. If you are going to just run on the standalone mode, then `https://127.0.0.1:9443+<port-offset>`/ will work.

rss-server-admin-userName - SuperAdmin/superadmin user with all privileges username.

rss-server-admin-password - SuperAdmin/superadmin user with all privileges password.

Please restart the server to get the changes reflected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sinthuja, I have updated my question and you could see the entire full stack trace. By the way i am using multi tenant mode for BAM.

Comment: I see you are using the h2 database for above for the MT case in BAM. There are some known issues in h2 database in MT mode. Can you please try with mySQL for this. For more information please refer [link](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Setting+up+BAM+server+in+Multi+Tenant+mode).